# Is there a way to use JavaScript for my build script instead of .CMD, .BAT or NAnt?

Tags: javascript, build, nant

Is there a way to use JavaScript for my build script instead of .CMD, .BAT or NAnt? I am getting tired or using a different language for my build and deploy scripts; surely there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, there are several implementations of JavaScript that can be used for shell scripting. Since you seem to be using Windows, there's the built in [Windows Script Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which can run command-line scripts via [`cscript.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xazzc41b%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org) is another option, which I use sometimes on *nix systems but haven't used on Windows..

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try [nscript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nscript), it is a npm package explicitly designed to replace bash or python like build scripts for those who are more comfortable with javascript. Any feedback is welcome!